# discover services using subtypes in jmdns

Tags: android, zeroconf, jmdns

I have registered my service with subtype using mdnsreponder(applebonjour) on my linux pc
. And I am trying to browse the service using jmdns (here I have jmdns.jar file) on my Galaxy phone .

I registered the service using the below command

```
$dns-sd -R SMARTCAM _smartplace._tcp.,**_wcam** local 80  "u=test"
```

When I browse with out subtype in the service type list of jmdns I get the proper response .
i.e

```
ServiceInfo[] https = jmdns.list("_smartplace._tcp.local.");
```

but If I try with the below options , It could not list anything -> response was null 
ServiceInfo[] https = jmdns.list("_wcam._sub._smartplace._tcp.local.");

```
$avahi-browse   _wcam._sub._smartplace._tcp.
```

It worked with the avahi browse  ..

Now can some one help me how to browse subtypes with jmdns .

Comment: Hi, I tried jmdns listby subtypes but still not able to print the subtypes ..                                                           Map<String, ServiceInfo[]> ressub = jmdns.listBySubtype("_wcam._sub._smartplace._tcp.local."); but still my return string is empty only .. Am i following the proper way to list subtype ..?

Comment: Mhh, I think that the name of the service remains the same, the subtype is probably stored somewhere in the serviceInfo Object and you have to get it manually. I'm just suggesting, not possible to check what i'm saying in the moment, sry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported by JmDNS. There is an open bug for this (http://sourceforge.net/p/jmdns/bugs/91/).

You will need to browse for the main type (no subtypes) and then do the filtering yourself (for example you can add a TXT record with a custom key, and then check that key on each service that is discovered).